# What is the fastest way to check for oddness & perform divisions by powers of 2

Tags: bit-manipulation, division, bit-shift, modulo

Often it is desired to check for oddness of a full number for various reasons, one such example is for a data grid where every odd line is a different color for readability. Programmers often implement such a feature using the formula

```
odd = n mod 2 != 0
```

Or the inverse:

```
even = n mod 2 == 0
```

but this method is slow as it requires the FPU to compute the remainder of the division.

I have also seen code where developers have written the following:

```
x = n / 2
odd = x mod 2
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You premise is false for many/most compilers.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - Indeed, which is why the answer points out that this doesn't just apply to compiled languages, and that many compilers already optimize for this.

Comment: You seem to have written the answer and the question at the same time.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - Correct, which is a feature of StackOverflow, it is encouraged.

Comment: @Geoffrey do you mean to say that _'it is encouraged to both post a question and an answer to the question simultaneously'_ or merely that it is encouraged to anwser one's own question?

Comment: @DavidTansey - See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Geoffrey -- thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is rather simple but often overlooked, please note though that this only applies to integers, not floats.

To involve the FPU on an x86 CPU to perform a division/modulus calculation requires a minimum of 17 clock cycles for single precision, or 34 for double precision.

So we can get a good idea of how many cycles the more complex example in the above code requires (best case not counting CPU load/store operations).

```
x = n / 2      17 cycles
odd = x mod 2  17 cycles
               ---------
               34 cycles
```

Because the computer represents integers in binary, we can simply check if a number is odd by checking if the first bit is set, this will work in any language that supports bit wise operations.

For example:

```
Psuedo Code: odd = n and 1
C/C++/Java : odd = n & 1;
```

The mask operation only requires 1 cycle, which is a **performance improvement of 17x to 34x per division/modulus operation** depending on the FPU mode.

For the division by 2 in the second example, it can be performed using bit manipulation, in fact, any division by a power of 2 can be performed using a bit shift right operation. For example:

```
Psuedo Code: x = n shr 1
C/C++/Java : x = n >> 1;
```

This will shift all the bits in `n` to the right by one thus performing a division by 2, if it was shifted to the right by two it would be a division by 4. This can be reverse to multiply in powers of two, but is not usually used in this manner as the multiply operation is just as fast.

If we combine these two techniques we can change the second example to:

```
Psuedo Code:
  x = n shr 1
  odd = x and 1

C/C++/Java:
  x = n >> 1;
  odd = x & 1;
```

This could be simplified further to

```
Psuedo Code: odd = (n shr 1) and 1
C/C++/Java : odd = (n >> 1) & 1;
```

In comparison to the version that uses the FPU, this version will use a total of just two clock cycles to perform the math which is a **performance improvement of 1700%**.

Many compilers know of these tricks and will just compile the code this way when it can for you, but many scripted languages are not as smart and not all compilers are equal.

For example, a compiler may not pick up on the following example usage:

```
int doMath(int x, int y) {
  return x / y;
}

doMath(10, 2);
doMath(20, 4);  
doMath(30, 8);
```

But if it was written using powers instead it would always be faster, ie:

```
int doMath(int x, int y) {
  return x >> y;
}

doMath(10, 1);
doMath(20, 2);
doMath(30, 3);
```

If you learn and leverage these tricks you will write very efficient code that works well everywhere without having to guess if the compiler will create good output for you, especially if you are cross compiling code between Microsoft/Intel and GCC as often done in platform agnostic projects.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're talking about floating point operations and the FPU if you only want to test integer values for odd/even-ness ?

Comment: @PaulR Because as the sample code that I see used extremely often (`i % 2`) uses the FPU and it can be avoided by simply checking the lowest bit.

Comment: That seems unlikely - why would any compiler generate FPU instructions for integer division ? See godbolt: https://goo.gl/s2ctRD

Comment: PaulR Reread the answer... "many scripted languages are not as smart and not all compilers are equal."

Comment: OK - so why even mention C/C++/Java and gcc then ?

Comment: Its psuedo/example code, not intended to target any language. Just because a compiler can 'magically' do this for you, doesn't mean you should rely on it, who knows where your code could end up, and what language it might be ported to.